IExceptionHandler not call when throw new exception .NET 8
I have sample code that uses IExceptionHandler in .NET 8.
Class ExceptionHandler:
public class ExceptionHandler : IExceptionHandler
{
    public async ValueTask<bool> TryHandleAsync(HttpContext httpContext, Exception exception, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        switch (exception)
        {
            case ArgumentNullException:
                await httpContext.Response.WriteAsJsonAsync(new ProblemDetails
                {
                    Status = StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest,
                    Type = exception.GetType().Name,
                    Title = exception.Message,
                    Detail = exception.Message,
                    Instance = $"{httpContext.Request.Method} {httpContext.Request.Path}"
                });
                break;

            default:
                await httpContext.Response.WriteAsJsonAsync(new ProblemDetails
                {
                    Status = StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError,
                    Type = exception.GetType().Name,
                    Title = ("Internal server error"),
                    Detail = ("Internal server error"),
                    Instance = $"{httpContext.Request.Method} {httpContext.Request.Path}"
                });
                break;
        }

        return true;
    }
}

Config in Program.cs:
builder.Services.AddExceptionHandler<ExceptionHandler>();
builder.Services.AddProblemDetails();
...
app.MapGet("/weatherforecast", () =>
{
    throw new ArgumentNullException();
});

But I got an error as shown in this screenshot:

Looks like my ExceptionHandler is not working ...
Please help me solve this problem.

This is a first chance exception. Continue execution and you'll see your custom code being executed.

@Tanveer Badar — Ha-ha, if what you suggested was really the issue, it will make a very funny example and a brilliant catch. :-)
